# Deploying Contract to Solidity shows only one function called "CALLDATA"

Tags: solidity, remix, error, calldata

I hope someone can help me as there might be an easy solution. I just started getting into writing smart contracts and thought the best way to learn is by looking at some Contracts, deploying them and playing around with it.

So when i copied a contract called PEPEBABY into my Remix compiler and deployed it on the Testnet, i only get one function "CALLDATA". Can someone help me and explain why the other functions are not showing here?

Here is the link to the Code on BscScan: https://bscscan.com/address/0x9427c5fed27c2b7e797b3b73e0da16da961df3a0#code

These are the Adress options shown: [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably deployed the wrong contract. What's the contract address and which network is it deployed on?

Comment: So i noticed i deployed the Address contract, which is probably wrong. But when i try to deploy PEPEBABY contract, i get the following error message:                   creation of PEPEBABY errored: VM error: revert.

revert
 The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only see "CALLDATA" under the deployed contract it's because you are deploying Address contract, not PEPEBABY

If you deploy PEPEBABY in Remix it will fail, because it is designed to be deployed only in BSC, Ethereum or Goerli. Notice in the constructor(), there is a router variable whose value depends on the network where it is deployed.

This one may be too complex to start learning, but if you want to make it work you will need to deploy it into a fork of any of the networks mentioned. But don't use the forks implemented in Remix because they may not work, use a tool like hardhat or anvil. You can search how to create an rpc endpoint with Alchemy and run a fork with hardhat to use it in Remix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i already used truffle from a SC Development course i did, that should work aswell right?I think i have all the basics to smart contracts, thats why i thought that might be a good idea to move forward like this.